# RichText Default Font Size

Tags: c#, fonts, formatting, rtf, richtext

I started with RichText, and i feel happy about the results i got.

So i have one small thing i don't understand. I wrote a Text like "Überschrift" and save the rtf to my databes. The result is like this...

```
{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri ;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\defchp \fs14}{\*\listoverridetable}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs14 Normal;}{\*\cs1\fs14 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs14 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs14\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs14\ql\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{\*\ts5\tsrowd\sbasedon4\fs14\ql\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}\nouicompat\splytwnine\htmautsp\sectd\pard\plain\ql{\lang2055\langfe2055\cf0 \u220\'dcberschrift}\par}
```

When i save this text to a file and save them to *.rtf and open in WordPad, my text "Überschrift" is Font-Size 12 ... (Is Default a saw on research)

My question is, can i force the RichTextEdit to save the fs\24? 
{\lang2055\langfe2055\cf0 \u220\'dcberschrift} normal but i try to get this 
{\lang2055\langfe2055\cf0 \fs24 \u220\'dcberschrift}

thanks for your informations

Comment: Are you creating this rtf in code or by a control? You may need to consider that RTF uses twice the actual font height, so to get 24pt you need to write \fs48..

Comment: i use a Control, but when i get the string (like this on top) i don't have the tag for the default font.

Comment: The default font is always `f0` but the fonts in the font table do not include the font size. However I can't even reproduce your results: When I create a RTBox with a Font of size `24` then the rtf-text is prefixed with `\f0\fs48`, as expected.